# gnuplot: plot graphs with complex analysis of points coordinates

Tags: function, plot, graph, gnuplot

Tell me PLZ how to plot the graph so that I can manipulate the y coordinate?

For example:

**before:**

```
plot inputFullPath using 1:2 with lines ls 3 notitle
```

**after:**

```
function func(y)
{
    return y * 3.14 + y * y / 1000;
}

plot inputFullPath using 1:my_func(2) with lines ls 3 notitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_func(y) = y * pi + y*y / 1000.
plot inputFullPath using 1:(my_func($2)) with lines
```

Note that "pi" is a pre-defined variable and that it is safest to put a decimal point after a floating-point constant